# Am I using @ModelAttribute wrong in my Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

For years I have been using @ModelAttribute to create and initialize my command object like so:

```
@RequestMapping()
public String someHandler(@ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean) {
  // Do something
}

@ModelAttribute("formBean")
public FormBean createFormBean() {
  FormBean formBean = new FormBean();
  // Do some sort of initialization
  return formBean;
}
```

In this example, I have a handler in a Controller that needs a FormBean, and a "create" method that gives it one if one isn't already in the Model (or session, if using @SessionAttributes).  So, when my someHandler() method is ran, the FormBean is already there and populated because my createFormBean() had already ran.

However, my colleague is claiming that, although this works just fine, that I am misusing the @ModelAttribute for a purpose it wasn't intended for, namely in the creation of the Command object.  In his interpretation from [the JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html), you should only use @ModelAttribute to create static data, like items used to populate a dropdown list or such.

I know this works for creating and initializing my Command object quite well, but am I using this for a purpose it was not originally intended for?  Am I breaking some cardinal rule here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ModelAttribute("formBean")
public FormBean createFormBean() {
  FormBean formBean = new FormBean();
  // Do some sort of initialization
  return formBean;
}
```

This can be useful if you need to initialize model attribute before binding form values from view. For example, you can query object from database (to get available it in current session).

In other cases I prefer to use this method:

```
@RequestMapping
public String someHandler(final Model model) {
  FormBean formBean = new FormBean();
  // Do some sort of initialization
  model.addAttribute("formBean", formBean);
}
```

I think it more clear to understand. But I don't think that you "breaking some cardinal rule here".

Comment: The one thing I like about using the first method is that you will get an instance of your form bean magically created by Spring when you hit your handler methods.  I did find out that you have to mark them public, else the CGLIB proxy runs and none of the dependencies are wired together.  I do agree, from a simple code reading perspective, that it does make it a little unclear how the form bean is being created, but I feel that if you are using Spring then you should already know.  Also, you should document your code anyway.