# Spring - Resolve from model to a certain subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form for creating an order. An `Order` has a `List` of `Product`s.

The post data may be something like:

```
client_id=123
product[0].id=1
product[1].id=10
product[2].id=14
```

The thing is, in my controller, I'm picking up the order with

```
@ModelAttribute("order") Order newOrder
```

I guess that's when Spring instantiates the Order object, sets its properties, and then tries to initialize the List and add all three Products.

This fails when `Product` is an abstract class, as is my case, and actually has 3 concrete subclasses. So, my question is: at what point and how can I tell Spring to instantiate the Products not directly but resolving to one of its subclasses?

(I can easily have in my form the discriminator value, like so:

```
product[0].id=1
product[0].type=typeA
product[1].id=10
product[1].type=typeB
product[2].id=14
product[2].type=typeA
```

)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978454/am-i-using-modelattribute-wrong-in-my-controller should work on abstract classes

Comment: I think that only way for you is to implement your own [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html). Here is [good tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-creating-a-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found that. I'm implementing it and will soon post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to implement my own Argument Resolver, as one of the comments pointed out.

```
public class OrderResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {


@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(Order.class);
}

@Override
public Order resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                             ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                             NativeWebRequest webRequest,       
                             WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory
                             ) throws Exception {

    Order order = new Order();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("product\\[(\\d+)\\]\\.type");

    for (String field : webRequest.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String type = webRequest.getParameter(field);

            Product product = null;

            switch (type) {
                case "typeA": product = new ProductTypeA(); break;
                case "typeB": product = new ProductTypeB(); break;
                case "typeC": product = new ProductTypeC(); break;
                default: continue;
            }

            product.setId(webRequest.getParameter("product[" + matcher.group(1) + "].id"));

            order.getProducts().add(product);
        }
    }       

    return order;

}
```